# async await not working properly in react js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await

I created a simple react js application, with async and await. but when I call the async function it's not waiting for the response from the ajax call.

```
class Test extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     this.getData();
   }

   async getData() {
     await this.props.getDataFromDB();
   }
}
```

If I add async to componentDidMount and use await this.getData(), it works fine. But when I call this.getData() it's not waiting for the result.

Why Is it so ?

Comment: Post `getDataFromDB` function also.

Comment: Well, `this.getData()` returns a promise. Why do you expect it to wait for that if you don't `await` it?

Comment: async/await does **NOT** make asynchronous function return a value synchronously

Answer (score 0):

The async await return a promise and this promise will not be catched if function calling the async function is not ready to wait for it. 
Also avoid using componentDidMount 'type' of lifecycle methods. 
Latest versions of the react introduced hook,  use 'useeffect' for component lifecycle methods.

Comment: A code sample would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an AsyncFunction object and so we need to make componentDidMount also an async function